# How to set priority in task in django-background-tasks?

Tags: python, django

I run django web in development mode in windows powershell on windows server. I had some issues to make different tasks with different priorities, and run them in parallel instead of one by one.

1. Tried to include "priority=1" in @background, it reported errors about no such parameters.
   @background(schedule=0, queue='1-qc-queue', priority=1)
2. I even run two queue like "1-queue" and "2-queue" in two windows powershell
   "python manage.py process_tasks --queue 1-queue"
   "python manage.py process_tasks --queue 2-queue"

but I saw all tasks are always with "priority=0" in background tasks table.

3. Tried to run multiple tasks in parallel:
   BACKGROUND_TASK_RUN_ASYNC = True
   but window powershell quit immediately

Answer (score 3):

Late answer but this question pops up first when googling for an answer to this question and isn't really addressed in the documentation.

To set the priority you send the priority as a kwarg to the task itself.

Example:
in tasks.py

```
@background(schedule=1)
def name(name):
    print(name)
```

in file calling task:

```
....
name('brian', priority=5)
....
```

Comment: Thanks. i will try it later. Do you use Huey and Redis together in windows environment? I am considering trying that since it seems be documented better than background tasks.

Answer (score 2):

To set priority for a task:

First, make the function a background task

```
@background(schedule=10)
def func(params):
    return
```

Now, set priority while calling the function:

```
func(params, priority=1)
```

You can also set negative priority:

```
func(params, priority='-1')
```